# Unable to verify raspbian OS using raspberry pi imager

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I'm trying to install raspberry pi OS on my SD card with the help of raspberry pi imager. the problem is that it writes successfully but when it's time to verify it ends with an error saying "Verifying write failed. Contents of SD card is different then what was written to it". I've been looking up everywhere for the solution but all I get is "fault in SD card" that's not the case with me, my SD card works fine. please help !! Hardware details: Raspberry pi 4 8gb variant Raspberry pi imager version : 1.6.2

Comment: Does the card boot a Pi?

Comment: @joan it worked, i used balena etcher to flash my sd it's working now

Comment: "my SD card works fine" how do you KNOW? Have you tried a NEW card? If the verify fails either the SD Card or the SD writer is faulty.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your SD card is bootable doesn't mean there is no corruption. Perhaps you just didn't access the corrupted files yet. Consider checking it with a tool you trust (I don't use the Pi imager so I don't know how reliable it is). Balena Etcher seems to have a validation option as well, make sure to use it when you flash.

Working with a corrupt SD card will cause you lots of pain in the long run. You might spend days trying to debug a script, only to find out that the error is caused by a corrupt Python library file. Checking an SD card only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't be so sure your card works fine. I once spent 2 hours on tech support with GoPro trying to get the firmware updated only to find that none of the new 32GB and better Samsungs I had would work, but an old crappy 2GB Kingston worked without a hitch.

This is just to say, don't waste a lot of time trying to fix the computer before just trying a reboot. Get a new card, see what happens. I bet you'll be happily surprised.